# Tight bound on spectral gap of compact homogeneous manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, laplacian, homogeneous-spaces

[This paper](http://www.springerlink.com/index/110J5634T1210717.pdf) by Peter Li proves a bound on the spectral gap of the Laplacian on a compact homogeneous manifold of diameter $d$:

$$ \lambda_1 \ge c/d^2, $$
where $c=\pi^2/4$. Can this bound be strengthened in a large number of dimensions, or is it essentially tight? In other words, if we restrict to manifolds of dimension $N$ what is the largest $c_N$ in which this bound is true?

For example, a square torus in $N$ dimensions has a spectral gap $\lambda \sim 1 $ but a diameter $\sim \sqrt{N}$, so this bound is far from saturation. 
Similarly, for the bi-invariant metric on SO(n), the spectral gap is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda \to 1/2$ whereas the diameter grows like $\sim \sqrt{n}$.
Very naively, this suggests that $c_N \sim N$.

Comment: I think if you take a product of a 1-D torus of size $1$ with $N-1$ sufficiently small tori, you will get an manifold of dimension $N$, diameter roughly independent of $N$, and spectral gap roughly independent of $N$, too.

Comment: You may be interested in [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.01108) by Judge and Lyons, specifically Theorem 1.3.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04259) studies the particular case of homogeneous metrics on the 3-sphere and the real projective 3-space. Among homogeneous metrics on $S^3$ or $P^3(\mathbb R)$, Theorem 1.4 ensures that $c\geq\pi^2$, but it is not clear whether this is sharp or not.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.

Comment: Here is the permanent link's article: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02566692